# Establishing communication between Host and Docker Containers

Tags: virtual-machine, suse, docker-network, sles

Suppose I have a host machine with SuSE Sles 11 Linux OS and on top of it I have a virtual machine with SuSE Sles12 OS in which I have docker installed. As we know the minimum requirement for docker to be installed is that it needs SuSE sles12, so that is the reason I have A virtual machine with sles12.

I created a docker container on the VM. If I want to communicate with host to the docker container. How is it possible? I know that I need to deal with bridge networking stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it tells mostly about the communication between the VM and the docker container, saying that we can expose the port. But i don,t need that. It can be done without exposing the port.

Comment: you need to mention your specific constraints and environment. Also mention your configurations involved

Comment: i explained in the question about the environment in which docker works and about the condition .